# Why does alum work on blisters in the mouth/cold sores?

Tags: treatment

Alum used to be an age old tradition to treat sores in the mouth and it worked beautifully.Foes anyone know why Alum works on sores in the mouth ?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take the guided tour and then read about how to ask a good question. You will see that you are expected to "Search and Research" before posting. Have you done this? If the articles you have found don't answer your question, reference them, say what they do say and why that is insufficient. Otherwise I am afraid your question is likely to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alum has been shown to be effective in treating [aphthous stomatitis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=alum%20canker%20sore) (canker sores) and it is believed to be due to the compound's **significant drying effect**. Alum is known as an astringent - a chemical compound that tends to shrink or constrict body tissues. More information on alum's astringent properties are reported in this [paper](https://academic.oup.com/chemse/article-lookup/doi/10.1093/chemse/bjw064). As the infected tissue shrinks there is a decrease in pressure due to swelling and this less pressure around the nerves in the affected area. The exact mechanism is still under question.